# javaFX errors (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)

Tags: java, javafx

i just want to run this project...
i've never seen it runned....
please help me
i just want to run these codes..

jdk 1.8.0.251

this is root.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="package_for_main.rootContoroller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="438.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="살자,">
         <font>
            <Font size="86.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="482.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="380.0" text="건강하게.">
         <font>
            <Font size="86.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="429.0" layoutY="462.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="ID">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="429.0" layoutY="516.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="PASSWORD">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="user_id" layoutX="575.0" layoutY="470.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="276.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="user_pass" layoutX="575.0" layoutY="524.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="276.0" />
      <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="587.0" layoutY="570.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Login">
         <font>
            <Font size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="signup" layoutX="587.0" layoutY="626.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Sign">
         <font>
            <Font size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this is rootController.java (i didn't do anything here)

```
package package_for_main;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public abstract class rootContoroller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button login;
    @FXML private Button signup;
    @FXML private TextField user_id;
    @FXML private TextField user_pass;
    @Override
    public void initialize(java.net.URL loaction, ResourceBundle resources) {
        
    }
}
```

and this is Appmain.java (i put controller and mainclass and xml at same pacakge)

```
package package_for_main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Appmain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Scene 객체 생성
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("살자, 건강하게.");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sorry for my poor english.
but i can read english at least.
so can you please help me??

and this is whole errors

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/abcd0/Desktop/WorkSpace/LiveAlive/Project/TeamProject/bin/package_for_main/root.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at package_for_main.Appmain.start(Appmain.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application package_for_main.Appmain
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: an abstract class class cannot be instantiated .. remove that modifier. And stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: jesus man thank you

Comment: who knows, maybe jesus was a woman :)